# Data Binding -> duplicate entry: android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.class

Tags: android, data-binding

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':myntraclone1:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.class

Have crossed checked it.

There is only one such class under `intermediates->debug->android.databinding`.
Can someone provide a way to mitigate it.

Comment: This is usually a problem with tests. You can exclude the DataBindingComponent from the test package explicitly.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same

Comment: I was using an own library project that uses databinding. After removing the dep the problem got resolved. Maybe your situation is similar to mine

Comment: yes,I did. I had databinding plugin applied in my library module which generated the duplicate class. Please check if u have the same issue. Cheers.

Comment: Try enabling multidex in your gradle and update the results.